# Images won't load on gallery

Tags: android

Hi my page will run with the names images 1,2,3 etc but the images won't appear any ideas?? Thank you for any help which is given!!

CustomSwipeAdapter.java

```
package com.example.kieranbroom.nextapp1;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomSwipeAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

private int[] image_resources = {R.drawable.images3,R.drawable.nextclothing1,R.drawable.product,R.drawable.mens};

private Context ctx;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

public CustomSwipeAdapter(Context ctx)
{
    this.ctx = ctx;
}


@Override
public int getCount () {
        return image_resources.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object o) {
    return (view==(LinearLayout)o);

}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View item_view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.swipe_layout, container, false);
    ImageView imageview = (ImageView)item_view.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
    TextView textView = (TextView)item_view.findViewById(R.id.image_count);
    textView.setText("Image : "+position);
    container.addView(item_view);
    return item_view;
}

@Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
container.removeView((LinearLayout)object);
}

 }
```

activity_gallery

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    ></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

CustomSwipeAdapter

```
package com.example.kieranbroom.nextapp1;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomSwipeAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    private int[] image_resources =         {R.drawable.images3,R.drawable.nextclothing1,R.drawable.product,R.drawable.    mens};
private Context ctx;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

public CustomSwipeAdapter(Context ctx)
{
    this.ctx = ctx;
}


@Override
public int getCount () {
        return image_resources.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object o) {
    return (view==(LinearLayout)o);

}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View item_view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.swipe_layout, container, false);
    ImageView imageview = (ImageView)item_view.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
    TextView textView = (TextView)item_view.findViewById(R.id.image_count);
    textView.setText("Image : "+position);
    container.addView(item_view);
    return item_view;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
container.removeView((LinearLayout)object);
}

}
```

GalleryActivity

```
package com.example.kieranbroom.nextapp1;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
 import android.widget.TextView;

    public class CustomSwipeAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
     private int[] image_resources =            {R.drawable.images3,
 R.drawable.nextclothing1,
R.drawable.product,
R.drawable.mens};
    private Context ctx;
     private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

     public CustomSwipeAdapter(Context ctx)
     {
        this.ctx = ctx;
        }


    @Override
     public int getCount () {
             return image_resources.length;
     }

    @Override
     public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object o) {
       return (view==(LinearLayout)o);

    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View item_view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.swipe_layout,    container, false);
            ImageView imageview = (ImageView)item_view.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
            TextView textView =     (TextView)item_view.findViewById(R.id.image_count);
        textView.setText("Image : "+position);
        container.addView(item_view);
        return item_view;
    }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object          object) {
        container.removeView((LinearLayout)object);
        }

    }
```